# How to specify no color in a ColorStateList?

Tags: android, android-support-library

I'm writing a really simple code but encountered a strange problem. I'm using a `ColorStateList` in order to tint my `AppCompatImageButton`. Here is the code:

*In layout:*

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_my_image"
    app:tint="@color/my_image_tint_color"
    app:tintMode="src_in"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
```

*my_image_tint_color.xml:*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/colorGray" android:state_enabled="false" />
    <item android:color="@color/colorAccent" />
</selector>
```

This code works correctly and it tints my image button with `colorGray` if disabled while it is tinted by `colorAccent` by default.

Now I want to change my button picture with an image with multiple colors. So I decided to tint my button with `colorGray` if disabled while keeping images original colors if not disabled. But now I'm stuck. Is there anything that defines *No Color* in android `ColorStateList`? Because I need to define a color for my default state in `ColorStateList`. If I don't specify anything for default state, Button will not be shown(it seems like transparent as default color and button will be tinted by transparent color). I tried to specify `@null` as color in color list, but it didn't work too.

I know I can do it in code, but I prefer to do this in XML. Is there any way to tint button gray if disabled while keeping original colors if not in XML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a while, I found a proper approach for my problem and since no one suggested correct approach, I decided to post it myself. Maybe it will be useful for someone else.

For my problem, I need to use `multiply` tint mode which can solve my problem. Here how you use it:

*In layout:*

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_my_image"
    app:tint="@color/my_image_tint_color"
    app:tintMode="multiply"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
```

*my_image_tint_color.xml:*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="#20909090" android:state_enabled="false" />
    <item android:color="#FFFFFFFF" />
</selector>
```

With this code, you see your button as full-colored when it is enabled. But if you disable your button, it becomes gray-scale.

**How this works:**

The `multiply` tint mode is defined by following equation:

> Multiplies the color and alpha channels of the drawable with those of
>   the tint. [Sa * Da, Sc * Dc]

This tint mode can only decrease color values, so it can used only to darken your colors. Just to understand following, remember that you need to scale 0x00-0xFF color values into 0.0f-1.0f, so 0x00 will be equal to 0.0f and 0xFF will be equal to 1.0f. In general it means you need to work with floating point values as color number where:

```
floating_point_color = byte_color / 255
```

In addition, remember that in 4 bytes color format like `#AABBCCDD`, `AA` is alpha, and other bytes show red, green and blue.

OK, how you use this feature for my problem?

1. I want to keep image colors when button is enabled. So I need to keep image alpha and colors as is. Then I need to use color `#FFFFFFFF` for my enable color. In this case color and alpha of each pixel of my original picture will be multiplied by 1.0f(since byte is 0xFF), so there will be no change in original image.
2. In order to gray scale my image in disabled mode, I used `#20909090` value. First I used `90` for red, green, and blue. Because I want to darken these color, but all in same scale. This darken all colors in same scale, so your color will not be something abnormal. With this scale a white color become light gray (0x909090) while black stay black. But then I used `20` for my color alpha to make resulting colors more transparent. In this way, if your image background is white, you will see a great toned down gray scale image from original image.

This solved my problem, but I find this as a really useful example of `tintMode` property. I will everyone enjoyed this small tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

You should have try with SRC_ATOP mode, I think it would have done what you expect.

*In layout:*

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_my_image"
        app:tint="@color/my_image_tint_color"
        app:tintMode="src_atop"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
```

*my_image_tint_color.xml:*

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:color="@color/colorGray" android:state_enabled="false" />
        <item android:color="@color/transparent" />
    </selector>
```

Comment: this works, basically uses tintMode the same as OP's answer, however this is easier as we can just use the original color without playing with multiplications. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Adding 00 in the beginning will make it 100% transparent and adding FF will make it 100% solid.
Suppose your preferred color is red #FF0000

So, 100% transparent color is: #00ff0000 and 100% solid color is: #ffff0000

And any value in between 00 to ff can be used to adjust the transparency.

So add the colors transparent in colors.xml and then access it from drawable

colors.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="trasnparent">#00ff0000</color>
</resources>
```

my_image_tint_color.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/colorGray" android:state_enabled="false" />
    <item android:color="@color/colorAccent" 
    <item android:color="@color/transparent" android:state_something="true"/>
</selector>
```

please let me know if it helps you and give a vote. Thanks

Comment: This does not work. If I tint my image with a `transparent` color, the image becomes transparent while I want to see image. What I want is to see image (somehow like no tint) for default while tinting gray for disabled state.

Answer (score 0):

You can add transparent color like  #00ff0000